# Laravel, how to ignore an accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model with a custom accessor so I get that custom attribute,

```
    class Order extends GSModel{

        $appends = ['orderContents'];

        public function getOrderContentsAttribute()
        {
            return $this->contents()->get();
        } 
 }
```

But now, in one case, I need to get only some fields, without this `OrderContents`  one.

```
$openOrders         = Order::open()->has('contents')->get(['id','date','tableName']);
```

But doing it this way, it returns me the `OrderContents` as well.. 
is there a way to not get that field?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you don't want `orderContents` when you convert it to JSON / an array?

Comment: Yeah, that would be enough

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's no way to do it in one go, so here's what you need:

```
$openOrders = Order::open()->has('contents')->get(['id','date','tableName']);

$openOrders->each(function ($order) {
  $order->setAppends([]);
});
```

Alternatively, you may use Laravel's [Higher Order Messaging](https://laravel-news.com/higher-order-messaging) on the last step:

```
$openOrders->each->setAppends([]);
```

Comment: Now it can be done like this: `$openOrders->each->setAppends([]);`

Comment: true, added @JordiPuigdellívol

Comment: protected $appends = ['full_name'];

    public function getFullNameAttribute() {
        return User::where('user_id',$this->id)->value('full_name');
    }


in this case, every time modal instance hit, then append method automatically trigged a sql query which need to remove.


public function scopeDisableDynamicAccessors()
    {
        $this->setAppends([]);
    }

Here setappends does not work

Answer (score 48):

Disappointing that people here gave you false information. There is in fact a built in method of achieving this, written straight into the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, called `Model::getOriginal`.

To retrieve the `foo` attribute, ignoring its accessor defined in `Model::getFooAttribute`, just call `$myModel->getOriginal('foo');`. This method is defined on line [3087](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3087) of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

Keep in mind that this method gets the *original* value on the model. This means that if you make any modifications to the attribute on that model instance, the above solution will not reflect those modifications. As long as you are just retrieving the value, you should have no problem.

Comment: And to get more than one like in the select?

Comment: this is so great and what ive been searching for... thank you

Comment: As of Laravel 7 you should use `getRawOriginal` instead or `getOriginal`

Answer (score 16):

For Laravel <= 6.x,

There is a built-in `getOriginal` method to get original value from model without accessor. see: [6.x](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L967)

```
$myModel->getOriginal('foo');
```

For Laravel 7.x & 8.x & 9.x,

You should use `getRawOriginal` built in method to retrive original value from model. see: [9.x](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1821)

```
$myModel->getRawOriginal('foo');
```

The `getOriginal` method in 7.x & 8.x & 9.x will return attribute value by passing through accessor.

Answer (score 13):

Okay I'm not saying this is a good solution, but it works and you get around using a loop...

Add this to your model:

```
public static $withoutAppends = false;

protected function getArrayableAppends()
{
    if(self::$withoutAppends){
        return [];
    }
    return parent::getArrayableAppends();
}
```

Then when you want to disable the `$appends` properties:

```
Order::$withoutAppends = true;
$openOrders = Order::open()->has('contents')->get(['id','date','tableName']);
```

Comment: I think it is a good solution, I understand that it avoids doing the queries to get the elements right? since my orderContents is a belongsToMany realtionship

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't load it somewhere else the relation won't be fetched. I don't really like the solution because it involves setting a static flag on the model. For example if you would have a second query with `Order::` you would have to worry about the state of `withoutAppends` and possible set it back to `false`. But ye... It does the job.

Answer (score 3):

The more consistent and reliable way to get the un-mutated value from within the model class is to retrieve it from the attributes property like this:

```
$this->attributes['name']
```

But be aware that attributes is a protected property, so you can't do that from outside the model class. In that case, you can use

```
$model->getAttributes()['name']
```

Works for me in Laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your model:

```
public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false): self
{
    $model = parent::newInstance($attributes, $exists);
    $model->setAppends($this->appends);

    return $model;
}

public static function withoutAppends(): Builder
{
    $model = (new static);
    $model->setAppends([]);

    return $model->newQuery();
}
```

Disable `$appends` temporarily:

```
$openOrders = Order::withoutAppends()->open()->has('contents')->get(['id','date','tableName']);
```

If you run a secondary query like
`$orders = Order::get();`
the appends are back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want the custom attribute value when a relation is loaded and contents() is a relation, you can do something like:

```php
public function getOrderContentsAttribute()
{
  if ($this->relationLoaded('contents')) {
    return $this->contents()->get();
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Then in order to access the attribute you can use a query scope to add a relation or `Order::with('contents')` when you're querying the model.