# Laravel ignore mutators

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel's Mutator functionality and I have the following Mutator:

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

**However I need to Ignore this Mutator in some cases.**
Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: If this functionality isn't always needed, surely it should be moved to the functionality where it is needed and remove the mutator?!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set a public variable in model, e.g $preventAttrSet

```
public $preventAttrSet = false;

public function setFirstNameAttribute($value) {
    if ($this->preventAttrSet) {
        // Ignore Mutator
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = $value;
    } else {
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
    }
}
```

Now you can set the public variable to true when want to Ignore Mutator according to your cases

```
$user = new User;
$user->preventAttrSet = true;
$user->first_name = 'Sally';
echo $user->first_name;
```

Comment: This doesn't work with query builder somehow, it reset to first state :(

Comment: never mind it works now [link](https://gist.github.com/fahmiegerton/90797448f034769c8daff315aa309020)

Answer (score 20):

Whereas the answers provided seems to work, there is a method in Laravel to access the original value:

```
$service->getOriginal('amount')
```

See this post:
[Example of getOriginal()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37060345/1314830)

Api:
[API Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal)

Comment: I think OP's question was how to set a raw attribute, and this does not answer the question.

Comment: If the code is handling a form save request, this would retrieve the old value that was loaded into the form instead of the new, current value.

Comment: As @Voyowsky points out, this ignores the property's `accessor` (only in Laravel < 8!!) not its `mutator`, which is not what OP asked for. It also doesn't get the current property's value, it gets the original value of the property (probably the DB's value), hence the name. In Laravel 8, `getOriginal()` is renamed to `getOriginalRaw()` and `getOriginal()` will use the accessor, as it should. Again, this isn't at all the right way to only get the raw value.

TL;DR: this answer is wrong. It also misinforms readers.

`original != raw`

Answer (score 17):

If you need to skip Eloquent Model mutators once in a while (for example in unit tests) you should use [setRawAttributes()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setRawAttributes):

```
$model->setRawAttributes([
  'first_name' => 'Foobar',
]);
```

Answer (score 6):

What the OP is really want is the Raw value from database which does not goes through the given mutator and everyone is suggesting `$model->getOriginal()` but when you run this method the value still come through the mutator. So the real answer would the

```
$model->getRawOriginal('first_name')
```

This will give you the raw value skipping the mutator.
[Laravel API: getRawOriginal](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getRawOriginal)

Comment: Actually what OP really wants is to *set* a value in the DB, not *get*.  They are after a *mutator*, not an *accessor*.  This answer (and some others here) confuse this and don't answer the question.

Comment: getRawOriginal worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've got some problems when using `setRawAttributes` so I decided to use this approach

```
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value, $ignore = false)
    {
        if ($ignore)
            $this->attributes['password'] = $value;
        else
            $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
```

When you want to ignore mutator you can use `$user->setPasswordAttribute('123', true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ignore mutators only on occasion - create another setter that doesn't go through the default mutation:

```
public function ignoreFirstNameMutator($value) {
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = $value;
}
```

---

```
$object->ignoreFirstNameMutator('Peter') //saves 'Peter'
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me :

```
$obj->getAttributes()['first_name']
```