# Temporarily disable Laravel appends

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to temporarily disable the `appends` functionality in `Laravel 5.4` during testing?

```
protected $appends = [
        'full_name',
    ];
```

I want to ignore that ^.

I've made a model factory but when I'm testing I don't want to have these append items on my model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, how to ignore an accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015039/laravel-how-to-ignore-an-accessor)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have had experience with this too. I've found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015039/laravel-how-to-ignore-an-accessor).

But, if you like a one-liner solution, you can also use the ff methods of Eloquent's `Model` class:

- `setHidden(array $hidden)`
- `makeHidden(array|string $attributes)`

You can check these [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setHidden).

Comment: I use `addHidden` method.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this:

```
/**
 * Get all appended items.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAppends()
{
    $vars = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);

    return $vars['appends'];
}

/**
 * Unset all appended items.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function unsetAppends()
{
    collect($this->getAttributes())->pull($this->getAppends());

    return $this;
}
```

But @elegisandi thanks that works great.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this code is suitable:
testing for Model name `Product` for example

```
// get product with "id = 1" for example
$needed_product = Product::find(1)->toArray();

// remove un-used attributes
$product = new Product;
foreach ($product->appends as $attr) {
    unset($needed_product[$attr]);
}
```

Now the `$needed_product` gets without any appends attributes