# Larave 10 - Eloquent Eager Loading without $append Attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Is it possible to have eager loading without `$append` attributes? I have following code:

**Product model:**

```
public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'product_category_id');
    }

public static function adminTableData(): Builder
    {
        return self::query()->select('*')
            ->with(['category' => function($query)
            {
                return $query->select('id', 'name');
            }]);
    }
```

**Company model:**

```
protected $appends = [
        'admin_table_logo',
        'edit',
        'remove',
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
public static function withoutAppends(): Builder
{
    $model = (new static);
    $model->setAppends([]);

    return $model->newQuery();
}
```

Modify adminTableData function

```
public static function adminTableData(): Builder
{
    return self::withoutAppends()->select('*')
        ->with(['category' => function($query)
        {
            return $query->select('id', 'name');
        }]);
}
```

The answer is based on [how to ignore accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015039/laravel-how-to-ignore-an-accessor)